# Bash: How to get different color for the command line and its output?

Tags: bash, bashrc

Basically, I am trying to edit my `.bashrc` such that when I type `ls` or whatever I type on the console, it will be displayed in Green color. At the same time, all the results / output displayed by `ls` or other commands (output from a python / java script) will be displayed in a grey color.

Is this possible ? What would I need to add into the `.bashrc` file ? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Well. Thank you very much for the answers and comments:

I saw from this [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146145/how-do-i-stop-a-bash-shell-ps1-color-to-stop-at-the-end-of-the-command) that I just have to add the following next to the definition of `$PS1`

`trap '[[ -t 1 ]] && tput sgr0' DEBUG`

Then it works. I am not sure there will be any issues. But it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
PS1="\[\e[m\]$PS1\[\e[32m\]"
trap 'printf "\e[m" > /dev/tty' DEBUG
```

That sets the colour to *green* just after the prompt and back to the default just before each command is executed (and before the prompt). Note that commands can still change the  colour of their output if they wish.

You may prefer to use a shell with proper syntax highlighting like `fish`, `fizsh` or `zsh` (with add-on) instead of `bash`.

Comment: @Gnouc it's not worded the best. But OP wants the command (what is typed) to be one color, and the output to be another color. Not a different color for each command.

Comment: @Patrick: ah, I got it. Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: If I use ls with `--color=always`, the output still with different colors.